# How to select elements with non-empty children

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to output all the information from a nodes children that are not empty.

What I have currently(not working): `Country/State/cities/city[string-length(*) != 0]/*`

Each city element has 4 child nodes: name, population, size, foundingDate.

I need to print all info for all the cities of all the states, but only the values that aren't null.

Odd sounding, I know.

What would be the proper way to do this?

**EDIT**: This is how the XML is formed. (I had written the path line above wrong, but fixed it.) Of course there are multiple State and City elements.

```
<Country>
  <State>
    <Name>stateName</name>
    <Cities>
      <City>
        <Name>cityName</Name>
        <Population>popNum</Population>
        <Size>citySize</Size>
        <foundingDate>foundingYear</foundingDate>
      </City>
    </Cities>
  </State>
</Country>
```

The objective is to output all the City info for the Country that does not have empty values. (The XML value isn't completed, but still needs to be searched.)

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPath to select all `City` elements in all `State` elements that have non-empty `Name`, `Population`, `Size`, and `foundingDate` children:

```
/Country/State/Cities/City[Name != '' 
                           and Population != ''
                           and Size != ''
                           and foundingDate != '']
```

### Update

Demo [**here**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3CCountry%3E%0A%20%20%3CState%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CName%3EstateName%3C%2FName%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CCities%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCity%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CName%3EcityName%3C%2FName%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPopulation%3EpopNum%3C%2FPopulation%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSize%3EcitySize%3C%2FSize%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CfoundingDate%3EfoundingYear%3C%2FfoundingDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FCity%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FCities%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FState%3E%0A%3C%2FCountry%3E&=&extract=%2FCountry%2FState%2FCities%2FCity%5BName%20!%3D%20%27%27%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20and%20Population%20!%3D%20%27%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20and%20Size%20!%3D%20%27%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20and%20foundingDate%20!%3D%20%27%27%5D&=&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=xml&output-format=xml&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2).

Comment: When I do that it just gives me city: repeatedly. No information.

Comment: The XPath is correct.  I've added a demo link to the answer for you.  Perhaps the code calling or using the results of the XPath call has an issue.